# How to make settings View in iOS

Tags: ios

it's probably a newbie question but it may help others.

I have made an iOS application with a main ViewController, a navigation Controller and a second view controller for my settings.

When i tap a button on the main view, it goes to the second (settings) View (segue push).
But when i come back to the main view, the main view is empty because it is reloaded.

Is there an easy way to keep the main view like it was before the loading of the settings or is it the normal behaviour and there's nothing we can do ?

And is there a specific component for making Settings views ? (some kind of table view with On/Off selectors or sliders)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating settings inside your app check this [**link**](http://inappsettingskit.com/).

> But when i come back to the main view, the main view is empty because
>   it is reloaded.

This won't happen in normal situation. I think you are doing something in your main view's `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods.

Please check that.